# Incorrect usage of setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

I've written a script that fires off 2 URLs based on some random number logic and I'm trying to set a delay before either one is fired (of half a second) but I don't think it's working properly. Am I doing this correctly? Code is below:

```
var clicks  = "http://www.urlone.com";
var impressions = "http://www.urltwo.com";
var randomNumber = (Math.random()*100);

function callOut() {
for (var i = 0; i < lengthVal; i++){
    if (randomNumber < 75) { 
        var randomCounter = (Math.random()*100);
            if (randomCounter < 50) {
                setTimeout("image1.src = clicks;",500);

            }
            else if (randomCounter > 50) {
                setTimeout("image1.src = impressions;",500);                    
            }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's wrong. Use `function(){ ... }` instead of `" ... "`. And, do not use a loop, but a function + counter (currently, all of your methods fire together after a half second).

Comment: what is clicks and impressions? use setTimeout(function(){image1.src=clicks;}, 500);

Comment: @RobW I've had to "answer my own question" but of course using all this excellent advice. Thanks to all for answers/comments though

Comment: Your function could never work, because you're not passing a function to setTimeout. Want me to edit your answer, or post a new one?

Comment: @RobW Please feel free to edit mine :)

Comment: @RobW thanks for the edit to my answer. I tried this method too (calling itself) but obviously hadn't done it properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duly noted about using setTimeout with a string. Here is how I ended up doing it. Is this the 'best' way to do this?

```
var clicks = "http://www.urlone.com";
var impressions = "http://www.urltwo.com";
var conversions = "http://www.urlthree";
var lengthVal = (Math.random() * 20 + 20);
var image1 = new Image();
var image2 = new Image();
var globalCounter = -1;



function callOut() {
    var ord = (Math.random() * 9999999999999) + "";

    var randomNumber = (Math.random() * 100);  // Random value for each call
    if (randomNumber < 75) {
        var randomCounter = Math.random() * 100;
        alert(randomCounter);
        if (randomCounter < 50) {
            image1.src = clicks + ord + "?";
        }
        if (randomCounter > 50) {
            image2.src = impressions + ord + "?";
        }
    }
    if (globalCounter++ < lengthVal) {
        setTimeout(callOut, 1000); // Call itself after another second
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` first parameter **should** be a function. Not string of code.

> code in the alternate syntax, is a string of code you want to execute after delay milliseconds. (Using this syntax is not recommended for the same reasons as using eval())

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)

```
setTimeout(function(){...}, 500);
```

Comment: A string containing code works too and is valid according to standards. Why are you saying it should be a function name (I take you mean a function reference)?

Comment: It is valid and completely legal though. Moreover `eval` is evil only when used with strings concatenated with variables (e.g. `eval("myvar = " + number)`).

Comment: Yes, and I am questioning that. I know that you did not write "must", but I don't see a reason why it "should" (as I've explained earlier). Let's say we differ in opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from here: http://www.codescream.com/?p=18 read it it should help :)

If you want to make a delay with setTimeout you should do exactly this:

```
setTimeout( function () {
      doThings()
}, 1000);
```

and never this:

```
setTimeout( "doThings()", 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout("image1.src = clicks;",500);
```

For this `image1` must be declared in a global context, like this:

```
var image1 = document.getElementById('image1');
```

But you better use a function here.

```
function setImageSrcClicks(){
    document.getElementById('image1').src = 'http://clicks_url';
}
setTimeout(setImageSrcClicks,500);
```

Comment: Sorry I left this out - it has already been declared, I've just left it out for some bizzare reason :S

Comment: If it's not working `image1` or `clicks` is not declared. For debugging try `setTimeout("console.log(image1, clicks);",500);`